# Chrome 36 - webkit animation error (everything disappears)

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, webkit

I’m working on a complex web-app. In particular, I’ve a search modal dialog that shows some results from a query. Today, the modal disappeared for a while during the execution.

Debugging and debugging, I found the reason: the ICON-SPIN!

For those unfamiliar to font-awesome, CSS class icon-spin adds an animation -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;

Such a tiny icon creates HUGE problems! Of course, in Firefox and Safari and IE (yep, even IE works!) everything runs smoothly.

And there is something that is even worse. I’m doing a fadeIn of a div (the panel with the result you see in the picture); well, fadeIn breaks it all.

Does anyone have the same problem?

(Images of the problem can be seen at [my blog on Medium](https://medium.com/@alex89x/chrome-36-webkit-animation-su-s-5d5e85f4af6e)

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, there is an open bug on Chromium for this:

[Bug reported on Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395213)